# Android camera calibration without chessboard

Tags: android, opencv, camera-calibration, 3d-reconstruction

I know there is some post talking about this topic but I could not find my answer.

I want to calibrate my android camera without chessboard for 3d reconstruction, so I need my intrinsic and extrinsic parameters.

My first goal is to extract the 3D real system to be able to put some 3d Model on screen.

**My step :**

- From a picture of a building I extract 4 points that represent the real 3D system
- /!\ this step require camera calibration /!\

  Convert them to 3d Point (solvePnP for exemple)
- Then from my 3D Axis I create a OpenGL projection and modelview matrix

My main problem is that I want to avoid a calibration step, so how can calibrate without chessboard? I have some data from android such as focal length. I can guess that the projection center is the center of my camera picture.

Any idea or advice? or other way to do it ?

Comment: You could improve your question by writing what have you tried, what have you read.

Comment: I'm working on this but some difficulties to understand http://www.cs.unc.edu/~marc/pubs/PollefeysIJCV04.pdf

Comment: Yes it is a hard topic but the article you have pointed is the right direction. Look for more resources about Structure from motion.

Answer (score 4):

here is nochess calibation of [qtcalib](http://w3.impa.br/~zang/qtcalib/nochess.html).

> This scheme is recomended when you need obtain a camera calibration
>   from a image that don't have calibration chessboard. In this case, you
>   can approximate the camera calibration if you know 4 points in the
>   image forming a flat rectangle in real world. Is important to remark
>   that the aproximated calibration depends on the 4 selected points and
>   the values that you will set for the dimensions of the rectangle

Comment: if I calib my an nexus 4 camera and get distorsion, skew factor and focal length, can I assume that all nexus4 camera hve the same value ?

Comment: No, not you cannot assume that. In general, if you want proper camera calibration you have to use a camera that cannot change the focus. Furthermore, the cameras of such mobile devices are usually not even suitable for static camera calibration, i.e., if you calibrate your Nexus 4 camera it does not guarantee that it is calibrated after using it for a while.

Comment: To be honest even though what the QtCalib offers seems to be working this is quite a task with all the parameters that the user has to enter some of which (example: dimensions of the plane) are quite difficult to extract with high enough accuracy (depends on the task at hand of course).

Comment: i have question now, i have a line with two point, after calibration
by your library,
i want to know where is my Line points location now ?
how i calculate new point ? because  i want two determine size of that
line after calibrate,
please help me to know whats formula to calculate :
(Xnew,Ynew)= Function(Kc,Rc,Tc)